# android - How to fix the position of view in Linear Layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am adding the LinearLayout(child view) to another LinearLayout(parentview) programatically here I want to set the position of child view to center_horizontal. How to do that? please can somebody help me.

```
code

LinearLayout linearLayoutstate = new LinearLayout(this);

linearLayoutstate.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

TextView stateTitletv = new TextView(this);

stateTitletv.setText("tv1");

TextView state_valuetv = new TextView(this);    

state_valuetv.setText("tv2");    

linearLayoutstate.addView(stateTitletv);

linearLayoutstate.addView(state_valuetv);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

LL_SelectedFilters.addView(linearLayoutstate,layoutParams);
```

Comment: I think the problem is that your child layout has a fill_parent width, so the horizontal aligning doesn't do much. Try it with wrap_content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this a minor change:::

```
  LinearLayout linearLayoutstate = new LinearLayout(this);

  linearLayoutstate.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
  linearLayoutstate.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

  TextView stateTitletv = new TextView(this);

  stateTitletv.setText("tv1");

  TextView state_valuetv = new TextView(this);

  state_valuetv.setText("tv2");

  linearLayoutstate.addView(stateTitletv);

  linearLayoutstate.addView(state_valuetv);

  LL_SelectedFilters.addView(linearLayoutstate,layoutParams);
```

Comment: You `setGravity()` on the child view, but this method will apply the gravity only on the children of this child view (`linearLayoutstate`): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setGravity%28int%29

Comment: then what were you want to set or if you want set it as LL_SelectedFilters.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

Comment: This is more like it, but it has the disadvantage of impacting ALL the children views of the parent layout.

Comment: if you can explain what exactly you want it would be better to me to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

The key to your problem resides in the `gravity` field of the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` of your child view:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lllp=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)linearLayoutstate.getLayoutParams();

lllp.gravity=Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
linearLayoutstate.setLayoutParams(lllp);

LL_SelectedFilters.addView(linearLayoutstate);
```